# Haskell - explanation of how `tell` works

Tags: haskell

I came across some code to log the recursive calls in a Fibonacci function. I have amended it so that is memoized. In any case I am struggling to understand how the `tell` function works... and how else I could track the calls in this function

```
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Data.Monoid
imoort qualified Data.Vector as V

fib :: Int -> Writer (Sum Integer) Integer
fib x = f x
  where
    fibs = f <$> (V.fromList [0..x])
    f 0 = return 0
    f 1 = return 1
    f n =  do a <- fibs V.! (n-1)
              b <- fibs V.! (n-2)
              tell (Sum 2)
              return (a + b)
```

A walk through of how `tell` works would be really helpful

Comment: As an aside, this does not look very memoized to me. Each recursive call to `fib` makes its own independent copy of the cache, resulting in only sharing the 2 calls in that scope. So instead of 2^n you get n^2 runtime. Better, but still bad.

Comment: Funny thing...  How `tell` works in this case is "very badly".  It leaks space because `Writer` is just broken with any `Monoid` instance where `mappend` is strict. And `mappend` for `Sum Integer` is strict.

Comment: @amalloy i have fixed it

Comment: @Carl any recommendation of what to do instead. and perhaps on explanation of `tell` because you seem to know it very well??

Answer (score 4):

> A walk through of how tell works would be really helpful

I try to use the two lines of code as below to show how `tell` function works:

```
...
tell (Sum 2)
return (a + b)
..
```

It is helpful to learn it from [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy.html#tell):

```
tell :: (Monad m) => w -> WriterT w m ()
tell w = writer ((), w)
```

and

```
writer :: (Monad m) => (a, w) -> WriterT w m a
writer = WriterT . return
```

so

```
tell (Sum 2) 
= writer ((), Sum 2) 
= WriterT . return ((), Sum 2)
= WriterT (Identity ((), Sum 2))
```

to create a value `WriterT (Identity ((), Sum 2))` of type `WriterT (Sum a) Identity ()`.

As `WriterT` is an instance of `Monad`, the expressions at the beginning of this answer can be translated as:

```
tell (Sum 2) >>= \_ -> return (a + b)
```

Now, we need to see how `>>=` work of `Writer Monad` from [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy.html#line-194) as below:

```
m >>= k  = WriterT $ do
    ~(x, w)  <- runWriterT m
    ~(y, w') <- runWriterT (k x)
    return (y, w `mappend` w')
```

To evaluate expression `tell (Sum 2) >>= \_ -> return (a + b)` step by step as below:

```
~(x, w)  <- runWriterT m
= ~(x, w)  <- runWriterT (tell (Sum 2))
= ~(x, w)  <- runWriterT (WriterT (Identity ((), Sum 2)))
= ((), Sum 2)
```

and

```
~(y, w') <- runWriterT (k a)
= ~(y, w') <- runWriterT ((\_ -> return (a + b)) ())
= ~(y, w') <- runWriterT (return (a + b))
= ~(y, w') <- runWriterT ( WriterT (Identity ((a + b), mempty))
= ((a + b), mempty)
```

And

```
return (y, w `mappend` w')
= return ((a + b), (Sum 2 `mappend` mempty))
= Identity ((a + b), Sum 2)
```

Note that `return` is overloaded the by inner Monad of `WriterT` not the `Writer Monad` itself.

Finally:

```
tell (Sum 2) >>= \_ -> return (a + b) = WriterT (Identity ((a + b), Sum 2))
```

And

```
f n = WriterT (Identity ((a + b), Sum 2))
```

Therefore, `tell` function just "insert" `Sum 2` to `Writer`.

Comment: I think you are confusing computation-level and type-level objects in this answer; e.g. you write `WriterT . return $ ((), Sum 2) = WriterT (m ((), Sum 2))`, but there's no `m` in scope at the computation level. This mistake is replicated several times. I also find your equations connecting `do`-syntax bindings to tuples imprecise, even flat-out incorrect.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank for your opinion. for `WriterT . return $ ((), Sum 2) = WriterT (m ((), Sum 2))`, Do you mean here cannot determine what the type of `return`? Actually, in this example, it is `Identity`, may be replace `m` by `Identity` will be more clear.

Comment: No, I mean I think you are imagining `m` to be the monad; but in that case `m` is a *type* and so not suitable for application to the computation `((), Sum 2)`. Types are never applied to computations in Haskell. Your example of `Identity` is especially confusing here, because we have a type-level name `Identity` and a computation-level name `Identity` that *are different*. So when you write `Identity ((), Sum 2)` instead of `m ((), Sum 2)`, you make the term more correct, but *not* because you replace type `m` with type `Identity` -- it is because you replace type `m` with *a computation*.